# Find piece of string inside array and do something if I can find it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Maybe it will work this time let's try...

Alright here's my problem,

This code currently works:

```
$(".threadTitle").each(function() {
    var colorBackground = "#F7F2ED";
    if ($(this).html().indexOf("Abraham") != -1) {
        $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().css("background", colorBackground);
        $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().find(".row1").css("background", colorBackground);
        $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().find(".row2").css("background", colorBackground);
    }
});
```

This is what I'm trying to do but doesn't work:

```
var titles = ["Abraham"];
$(".threadTitle").each(function() {
    var colorBackground = "#F7F2ED";
    var realTitle = $(this).html();
    if (titles.indexOf(realTitle) > -1) {
        $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().css("background", colorBackground);
        $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().find(".row1").css("background", colorBackground);
        $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().find(".row2").css("background", colorBackground);
    }
});
```

## SOLUTION PROVIDED BY @Jason P

```
var realTitle = $.trim($(this).text());

for (var i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) {
    if (realTitle.indexOf(titles[i]) > -1) {
        $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().css("background", colorBackground);
        $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().find(".row1").css("background", colorBackground);
        $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().find(".row2").css("background", colorBackground);
        break;
    }
}
```

## SOLUTION I FOUND OUT

```
var wordsOrPhrases = ["Abraham", "how are you"];
$(".threadTitle").each(function() {
    var realTitle = $(this).text();
    var asdasdasd = wordsOrPhrases.filter(function(x) {
        return realTitle.indexOf(x) > -1;
    }).length > 0;
    if (asdasdasd) {
        $(this).css("background", "#F7F2ED");
    }
});
```

### Fiddle & Speed Tests

http://jsfiddle.net/aYc2d/

http://jsperf.com/testestringinsidearray

Thanks to everyone who helped me.

Comment: It helps people help you if you describe in detail exactly what "doesn't work" means. Are there errors reported?  Does *anything* happen?

Comment: Added some images to help explain it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question still isn't explained very well, but I think I have it.

You're asking why this returns true:

```
if($(this).html().indexOf("Title A") != -1) {
    //should get here
}
```

But this doesn't:

```
var titles = ["Title A"];
var realTitle = $(this).html();
if (titles.indexOf(realTitle) > -1) {
    //should get here
}
```

The difference has to do with the difference between `string.indexOf()` and `array.indexOf()`.

`string.indexOf()` searches for the specified text anywhere in the string.

`array.indexOf()` searches for the specified object (doesn't have to be a string) anywhere in the array.

**Edit** From your picture, I can see that your span contains a lot of whitespace. Try changing to this:

```
var realTitle = $.trim($(this).text());
```

**Edit 2** in response to your comment:

In that case, you'll need to iterate the array and do `indexOf` on each item. I think this is what you want:

```
var realTitle = $.trim($(this).text());

for (var i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) {
    if (realTitle.indexOf(titles[i]) > -1) {
        $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().css("background", colorBackground);
        $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().find(".row1").css("background", colorBackground);
        $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().find(".row2").css("background", colorBackground);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked... kinda... let's say threadTitle was "Hello World 12345", with the first code I could do .indexOf("Hello World") and it would find it, with this second one using arrays I can't, it just works if I do exactly indexOf("Hello World 12345").

Comment: @GabeNewell Edited to respond.

Comment: I found another way but yours works perfectly and is in fact even faster, I'll add both of them to the OP and include the speed test. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

First, you probably want `$(this).text()` rather than `.html()`, in case you have nested spans or something (though you shouldn't).

But that shouldn't cause the problem you're getting. You must have a difference in the html between the two examples or something.

Comment: Same thing with var realTitle = $(this).text().trim(); but thanks for the tip, I didn't knew about trim I can use it for something else.

Comment: @GabeNewell `.trim()` isn't supported in all browsers, so you might want to use `$.trim($(this).text())`

Comment: I think you have to have an html difference between your two examples. Also, the fact that you're selecting `.row1` and `.row2` is a little bit fishy. Showing your html would help